# Different Text size (eg. LastName,FirstName/FirstName) for button in responsive design bootstrap using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am working on my assignment , i am almost done with the code. i just need help on a unique design.

I have 3 buttons with some text. For full screen the text is say `"HelloWorld"`, `"LastFirst"` but when the same website is seen on mobile , the text of those 3 buttons change to "Hello","Last" etc.

I have few things in mind, having the text as Label. If i give id to those labels and hide the label when required.

I would like to know if there is any correct or simpler way to do it?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: best is to use media queries

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/cjqr9gAYLJ  check the link and click mobile icon on righthand top corner then resize the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Bootstrap.

Bootstrap has these .visible-xs and .hidden-xs classes ([more here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities))

.hidden-xs class helps you hide an element only on mobiles.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  Hello <span class="hidden-xs"> World </span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  Last <span class="hidden-xs"> First </span>
</button>
```

If you are not using bootstrap, you can achieve the same using media queries.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  Hello <span class="hidden-xs"> World </span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  Last <span class="hidden-xs"> First </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Everyone, hidden-xs thing was the one i was looking for. It works perfectly.